# Remove every website ending with .com except one using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently struggling with regex. I'm trying to substitute every website ending with a ".com" except one, that is "crypto.com" as it's not a website per se but also the name of a cryptocurrency.

Let's take this sentence:

"Here are my favorite things: crypto.com, polo.com, cryp.com and google.com"

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573284/regex-replace-every-url-except-one), this is my Python regex:

`r"(\w+\.)?crypto\.com"`

The problem, using https://regex101.com to test it out, is that it's capturing only the crpyto.com, but not the others (which is what I want to do).

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?
Thank you!

Expected code:

```
text = "Here are my favorite things: crypto.com, polo.com, cryp.com and google.com"    
text = re.sub(r"(\w+\.)?crypto\.com", '', text )
```

Expected output:

"Here are my favorite things: crypto.com,,  and "

Comment: Please add the exact output you expect here.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\s*\b(?!crypto\.)\w+\.com\b', '', text)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I added the desired output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using your regex, the only thing that's being replaced is the polo.com

Comment: Why? See https://regex101.com/r/BWtX6c/2. I tried to make it a bit more comprehensive, see https://regex101.com/r/BWtX6c/1. You may add `rstrip(',')` in Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\s*\b(?!crypto\.)\w+\.com\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BWtX6c/2). *Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!crypto\.)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `crypto.` string immediately to the right of the current location
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\.com` - `.com`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/8mA53W):

```py
import re
text = "Here are my favorite things: crypto.com, polo.com, cryp.com and google.com"
print( re.sub(r'\s*\b(?!crypto\.)\w+\.com\b', '', text) )
# => Here are my favorite things: crypto.com,, and
```

A more comprehensive regex can also be used to remove commas and the word `and`:

```py
(?:\s*(?:,|and\s*)?)\b(?!crypto\.)\w+\.com,?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BWtX6c/1).

Comment: I copy/paste yours and for an unknown reason (maybe there was a typo I didn't spot...) it didn't work. However, your demo works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Jauhnax How strange, I also copied the code from my comment and pasted into ideone.com. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look-around:

```
(\w+)?(?<!crypto)\.com
```

Edit: The question changed slightly
I removed a `\.` that was incorrect, now it should work!

Comment: Your regex will fail to match `crypto.com` in `decrypto.com`.

Comment: As I understand, OP would not want to match that. Or is decrypto.com another cryptocurrency? In this case, they do want that.

Comment: `crypto` and `decrypto` are different words. The requirement is to only fail *one* word, `crypto`.